# How to make hidden nodes selectable

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there any way to make hidden nodes selectable? Once a user selects and hides say a couple of nodes of a model in the viewer they become transparent, but not selectable anymore.

I've tried the following, but the code doesn't do anything. I'd expect the transparent nodes to become selectable by LMB clicking onto them in the viewer canvas.

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.HIDE_EVENT, evt => {
    viewer.lockSelection(evt.nodeIdArray, false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you hide an object or node, hitTest will not work, so you can't select through UI, you can only select programmatically. You can check this in the console.

```
//replace dbid with real one.
NOP_VIEWER.hide(dbid)
NOP_VIEWER.select(dbid)
```

Comment: Alright, but how'd you get the dbId of node from wherever is user clicking on the viewer canvas?

Comment: You can select an object and run NOP_VIEWER.getSelection() in console, you'll get the dbid. or use SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT.
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, onSelection)

function onSelection(event) {
    event.dbIdArray.forEach(selection => {
        console.log(`selected ${selection}`)
    });
}

Example: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/interactive_examples/example_2/

Comment: Are you sure that `Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` triggers for components that cannot be selected?

Comment: that code is before you hide, to get the dbids. If you already have a set of dbids to hide and select, then no need for this.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the user could hide multiple dbIds and so it's impossible to figure out which one they want to select from all those that are currently hidden.

Comment: there's a workaround, instead of hiding you can make them transparent, transparent objects will be detected by hitTest.

Comment: sorry about the late reply, thank you for letting me know about hitTest